# qt working very slow on windows

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am working on opencv and qt project.it 's working very quickly on linux but it is working very slow on windows.Linux OS is 64 bit ,windows 64 bit too.I didnt understand the problem.Thanks (sorry for my english)

following code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/base.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/types.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect_c.h>
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video camera no. 0



    namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"
    // Load Face cascade (.xml file)
        CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
        face_cascade.load( "xml/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" );

    while (1)
    {
        Mat frame;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

         if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
             cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
             break;
        }
         // Detect faces
             std::vector<Rect> faces;
             face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

             // Draw circles on the detected faces
             for( int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
             {
                 Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 );
                 ellipse( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );


                     imshow( "Detected Face", frame );
             }



                 //rectangle( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width*2, faces[i].height*2), Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ) );




        if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
       {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break;
       }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: where's Qt in your code? Do you use the same camera/resolution in windows and linux setup?

Comment: what is the problem? work in linux :) or, develop/test on linux, then, if it's needed, on windows built release versions only. of course, it is actual only for os-independed code

Comment: but i want to develop in windows.

Comment: I guess qt using a 32-bit compiler in windows but linux use 64 bit. Could it be the program?

Comment: Most likely you're testing a debug build. These can be slow.

Comment: i decide to work in linux world :)